# Converting one dimesion array into 2 dimensions array of 9 columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The following code is supposed to take a String array  of one element ,splits it into

nine elements those nine elements  should be store into another array of two dimensions .

each element of them should be store in a column alone.

But when I print the elements of the two dimensional array the last element only is printed 
Why?

```
public class StringFragementation {
    public static String[][] mymethod(String[] mystring) {
        String[][] india = new String[1][9];
        String mystringno2[];
        mystringno2 = mystring;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        String x = "_";
        int i1;
        do {
            i = mystringno2[j].indexOf(x, i);
            i1 = i + 1;
            i1 = mystringno2[j].indexOf(x, i1);
            if (i1 <= -1) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
            int row, col = 0;
            for (row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
                for (col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                    india[row][col] = mystringno2[j].substring(i, i1);
                }
            }
        }
        while (j < mystringno2.length);
        return india;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] singapore = new String[1][9];
        String[] s = {"_Netherlands_Iceland_Norway_Denmark_Usa_Brazil_Argentina_Colombuia_Bolivia_"};
        singapore = mymethod(s);
        for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                System.out.print(singapore[0][0] + "\t");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: use this. System.out.print(  singapore[row][col]  +"\t")   ;

Comment: It gives the same result

Comment: you missed out one open bracket near for(int row=0;row<1;row++)  check my answer

Comment: Not an answer, but what is `for(int row=0;row<1;row++)` used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is here :

```
for( row=0;row<1;row++){
 for( col=0;col< 9;col++) {
   india[row][col] = mystringno2[j].substring(i, i1);
}
}
```

you fill the 9 column by the same word because the `i` and `i1` never change through this loop , then restart the array  and fill  with `Netherlands` then `Iceland_Norway_Denmark` until the last word
`Bolivia` , so your array fill with `Bolivia` in 9 columns

the correct way is :

```
int row = 0, col = 0;
    String[][] india = new String[1][9];
    String mystringno2[];
    mystringno2 = mystring;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    String x = "_";
    int i1;
    do {
        i = mystringno2[j].indexOf(x, i);
        i1 = i + 1;
        i1 = mystringno2[j].indexOf(x, i1);
        if (i1 <= -1) {

            break;
        }
        i++;
        india[0][col] = mystringno2[j].substring(i, i1);
        System.out.println("dfref   " + row + "  " + col + "   " + india[row][col]);
        col++;

    } while (j < mystringno2.length);

    return india;
```

and in the `main` :

```
for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                System.out.print(singapore[row][col] + "\t");
            }
        }
```

---

there are a smallest way to do this split , look at this code :

```
class StringFragementation {

    public static String[] mymethod(String mystring) {
        String[] split = mystring.split("_");
        return split;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] singapore = new String[9];
        String s = "Netherlands_Iceland_Norway_Denmark_Usa_Brazil_Argentina_Colombuia_Bolivia_";
        singapore = mymethod(s);
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            System.out.println(singapore[col]);

        }
    }
}
```